# How to increase size of JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist

In the NetBeans the height of row is capable of only one line.
I want to increase the size of JList vertically.
In the JList height of the row should atleast of 3 lines.

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: Have you referred to JList documentation yet? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html

Comment: *"height of the row should atleast of 3 lines."*  This 'list' seems more like a 'table'.  Consider using a `JTable` with 3 columns instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use the method [`setVisibleRowCount(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setVisibleRowCount%28int%29)

```
JList list = new JList();
list.setVisibleRowCount(3);
```

to increase the height of all "cells" of the list, you can either:

- Increase the font size of the list with: `list.setFont(list.getFont().deriveFont(22.0f));`
- Force the height of all cells with `list.setFixedCellHeight(44);`
- Change the `ListCellRenderer` to return whatever you want and possibly alter the preferred size of the renderer which can be different for each value of the list: `list.setCellRenderer`

Comment: setVisibleRowCount(int visibleRowCount) 
          Sets the visibleRowCount property, which has different meanings depending on the layout orientation: For a VERTICAL layout orientation, this sets the preferred number of rows to display without requiring scrolling; for other orientations, it affects the wrapping of cells. (I don't think the problem is here but in the way JList is added to its container)

Comment: +1 - @AshishKudale slightly astonishing that it shows 1 row only, the default of this setting is something like 8 or 12 (didn't check the exact number)

Comment: @Alepac without more explanations from the OP, it is pretty much impossible to guess what he did wrong and AFAICT, my post directly answer his question. If this is not what he looks for, he can always refine his question and answers will in turn be adapted.

Comment: hey bro @Guillaume Polet i know setVisibleRowCount(int); i want to increase the height of each row provided by JList.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about each individual row being able to display more than one line then you can use a custom renderer to display multiple lines of data. See [Writing a Custom Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer) for more information.

Or another way is to add data to the model using HTML strings. For example:

```
String rowOne = "<html>1<br>2<br>3<br></html>";
```

Now the data for this row will displayed on 3 lines.

Comment: hmmm ... even with the little information the OP is giving, thinking _renderer_ feels a bit far fetched to me :-)

Comment: it's working thanks but, what about when data is coming from Database

Comment: I can't help you. Only you know the format of your data and how you want it to be displayed.